Updating configuration when migrating from .NET Framework to .NET 8
I've been tasked with updating a .NET Framework application to .NET 8. I ran Microsoft's migration tool, and it seemed to go well, with no errors, but I don't know if there's anything else I need to do. Trying to run the application locally for the first time, I'm getting this error:
[]
EDIT: The value of config is null and is throwing a null reference exception. So the issue is with config, but I don't know how to fix it.
Program.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GenericEmail
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                if (args.Length > 0)
                { 
                    ConfigSettings config = new ConfigSettings();


                //the below will be passed in as parameters
                config.reportType = args[0];
                bool isAdminReport = false;
                bool isTest = true;
                
                if (args.Length > 1)
                {
                    isAdminReport = Convert.ToBoolean(args[1]);
                }

                if (args.Length > 2)
                {
                    isTest = Convert.ToBoolean(args[2]);
                }

                config.isAdminReport = isAdminReport;
                config.isTest = isTest;

                //the below are pulled from config file - specific to reportType param

 -----> THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION IS TRIGGERED-------->  config.emailSubject = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSubject-" + config.reportType];
                    config.adminEmailAddresses = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Admin-" + config.reportType];
                    config.noErrorMessage = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NoError-" + config.reportType];`

Here is App.config:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=mytoken" requirePermission="false"/>

  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
  </startup>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="TestEmailAddress" value="me@email.com"/>
    <add key="EmailServer" value="smtp.myserver"/>
    <add key="EnableSSL" value="false"/>
    <add key="Port" value="25"/>
    
    <add key="EmailSubject-Validation" value="Account # Errors and Unreconciled Jobs"/>
    <add key="Admin-Validation" value="1@email.com; 2@email.com;  3@email.com; 4@email.com"/>
    <add key="NoError-Validation" value="There are no validation errors to report at this time."/>

    <add key="EmailSubject-Blackout" value="Important: AESOP time entered on blackout date"/>
    <add key="Admin-Blackout" value="me@email.com; x@email.com"/>
    <add key="NoError-Blackout" value="There are no absences on blackout dates to report at this time."/>

    <add key="EmailSubject-FFCRA" value="Authorization required for your absence entry"/>
    <add key="Admin-FFCRA" value="me@email.com; x@email.com"/>
    <add key="NoError-FFCRA" value="There are no FFCRA absences to report at this time."/>
    <add key="Sender-FFCRA" value=" y@email.com"/>

    <add key="EmailSubject-FFCRAReport" value="AESOP FFCRA Absence Report"/>
    <add key="Admin-FFCRAReport" value="me@email.com; y@email.com"/>
    <add key="NoError-FFCRAReport" value="There are no FFCRA absences to report at this time."/>
   
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mu_report_dataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/mu_report_data.csdl|res://*/mu_report_data.ssdl|res://*/mu_report_data.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myserver;initial catalog=mytable;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=mytoken" serviceUri=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=mytoken" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>

It's been years since I've done any .NET coding and I barely remember anything. Any help is greatly appreciated!

.NET 8 is .NET Core 8 and uses a completely different and far better configuration model. app.config files are no longer used. I suspect ConfigSettings is your own custom class because .NET Framework has no such class. Check Configuration in .NET to see how the Configuration works now.

Also check the Options pattern because I suspect it's the built-in implementation of what you tried to create with ConfigSettings: a strongly typed settings object created from configuration settings.
